# MailKit: SearchQuery.SubjectContains method not returning the right amount of emails from inbox

Tags: c#, .net, email, .net-core, mailkit

I got some trouble with the following query:

```
var inbox = ImapClient.Inbox;
await inbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadWrite, CancellationToken.None);

var uniqueIds = new List<UniqueId>();

var query = SearchQuery.SubjectContains("RandomName");
uniqueIds.AddRange(await inbox.SearchAsync((query), CancellationToken.None));
```

I am getting 168 mails but in the inbox folder there are more of 20.000 email with "RandomName" as part of the subject.

I also tried with HeaderContains method as follow:

```
var query = await inbox.SearchAsync(SearchQuery.HeaderContains("Subject", "RandomName"));
```

And I get the same 168 emails.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the client library. If the server only returns 168 matches, then as far as the client knows, there are only 168 matches.

There is either a server bug or the folder you are searching in your webmail view is pulling in messages from other folders.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem is there is only one Inbox folder in my webmail and no matter when I try to search those emails, I always get 168 matches or less.